# How can I add a foreign key to a JSF page?

Tags: jsf

i am trying to create a jsf page that shows a post and users can write comments on it . so in the comment table have a foreign key that references to the post . 
my question how can I add the attribute Idea "Idee" to the comment "Avis" entity ?

this is index.xhtml

```
 <p:outputPanel>
            <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="5">
                <h:outputText value="#{msg['idee.titre']}" />
                <h:outputText value="#{in.titre}" style="font-weight: bold"/>

                <h:outputText value="#{msg['idee.description']}" />
                <h:outputText value="#{in.description}" style="font-weight: bold"/>

                <h:outputText value="#{msg['idee.theme']}" />
                <h:outputText value="#{in.theme}" style="font-weight: bold"/>
                 <h:outputText value="#{msg['idee.type']}" />
                <h:outputText value="#{in.type}" style="font-weight: bold"/>

                <h:inputText value="#{avisBean.avis.commentaire}" />
                <p:commandButton value="commenter" icon="ui-icon-check" action="#{avisBean.addAvis}" >

                </p:commandButton>
            </h:panelGrid>
        </p:outputPanel>
```

this is Avis.java

```
 @Entity
@Table(name = "avis")
public class Avis implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    @Column
    private String commentaire;
    @Column
    private int score;

    @Column
    private Boolean signaler;

    @Column
    private Boolean satisfaction_utilisateur;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "idee_id")
    private Idee idee;


    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="user_id")
    private Utilisateur user_avis;
```

this is Idee.java

```
   @Entity
    @Table(name = "idee")
    public class Idee implements Serializable {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        private int id;
        @Column
        private String titre;
        @Column
        private String description;

        @Column
        private String theme;

        @Column
        private String type;

        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "idee")
        private Collection<Avis> avis;
        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name="user_id")
        private Utilisateur user;
```

Comment: Did you mean adding _that foreign key_ to JSF form instead of entity ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are showing multiple Ideas "Idees" in a single page, then what you can do is pass the "idee" object to the `#{avisBean.addAvis}` method:
in your xhtml page:

```
<p:commandButton value="commenter" icon="ui-icon-check" action="#{avisBean.addAvis(in)}" >
```

and in your bean something like this:

```
public String addAvis(Idee idee){
    //add your avis to your idee here
}
```